# Inserts don't persist

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, sqlite, ionic-framework

I'm working on a two-screen demo Vue app with Ionic, the Capacitor Community SQLite package, and the sqlite-vue-hook. I can't get inserts to persist in the database.

## Database

One table called `contacts` that gets created in `main.ts` :

```ts
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router';

import { IonicVue } from '@ionic/vue';

/* Core CSS required for Ionic components to work properly */
import '@ionic/vue/css/core.css';

/* Basic CSS for apps built with Ionic */
import '@ionic/vue/css/normalize.css';
import '@ionic/vue/css/structure.css';
import '@ionic/vue/css/typography.css';

/* Optional CSS utils that can be commented out */
import '@ionic/vue/css/padding.css';
import '@ionic/vue/css/float-elements.css';
import '@ionic/vue/css/text-alignment.css';
import '@ionic/vue/css/text-transformation.css';
import '@ionic/vue/css/flex-utils.css';
import '@ionic/vue/css/display.css';

/* Theme variables */
import './theme/variables.css';

/* SQLite imports */
import { defineCustomElements as jeepSqlite, applyPolyfills } from 'jeep-sqlite/loader'
import { Capacitor } from '@capacitor/core'
import { CapacitorSQLite, SQLiteConnection, SQLiteDBConnection } from '@capacitor-community/sqlite'
import { useState } from '@/composables/state'
import { deleteDatabase } from '@/utils/sqlite/delete-db'

applyPolyfills().then(() => {
  jeepSqlite(window)
})

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {
  const platform = Capacitor.getPlatform()
  const sqlite: SQLiteConnection = new SQLiteConnection(CapacitorSQLite)

  const app = createApp(App)
    .use(IonicVue)
    .use(router);
  
  // existing connections store
  const [existConn, setExistConn] = useState(false)
  app.config.globalProperties.$existingConn = { existConn: existConn, setExistConn: setExistConn }

  try {
    if (platform === 'web') {
      // create the 'jeep-sqlite' Stencil component
      const jeepSqlite = document.createElement('jeep-sqlite')
      document.body.appendChild(jeepSqlite)
      await customElements.whenDefined('jeep-sqlite')
      
      // initialize the web store
      await sqlite.initWebStore()
    }

    // SQLITE STUFF
    const ret = await sqlite.checkConnectionsConsistency()
    const isConn = (await sqlite.isConnection('ionic-vue-db', false)).result

    let db: SQLiteDBConnection

    if (ret.result && isConn) {
      db = await sqlite.retrieveConnection('ionic-vue-db', false)
    } else {
      db = await sqlite.createConnection('ionic-vue-db', false, 'no-encryption', 1, false)
    }
    console.log(db)

    // DELETE THE DATABASE TO START CLEAN
    //await deleteDatabase(db)

    // CREATE SCHEMA AND PUT SOME TEST CONTACTS IN
    await db.open()

    const createContactsTableRes = await db.execute(`
      CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contacts (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        first_name TEXT NOT NULL,
        last_name TEXT NOT NULL,
        email TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
      );
    `)

    if (
      createContactsTableRes.changes && 
      createContactsTableRes.changes.changes && 
      createContactsTableRes.changes.changes < 0
    ) {
      throw new Error('Error: creating contacts table failed')
    }

    // const contactsToInsert = [] as any[]
    // contactsToInsert.push(
    //   ['Person', 'One', 'person1@person1.com'],
    //   ['Person', 'Two', 'person2@person2.com'],
    //   ['Person', 'Three', 'person3@person3.com'],
    // )
    // const contactsPlaceholders = contactsToInsert.map(() => '(?, ?, ?)').join(',')
    // const insertTestContactsQuery = `
    //   INSERT INTO contacts (first_name, last_name, email) VALUES ${contactsPlaceholders};
    // `

    // await db.run(insertTestContactsQuery, contactsToInsert.flatMap((el) => el))

    console.log(await db.query('SELECT * FROM contacts;'))

    await sqlite.closeConnection('ionic-vue-db', false)

    router.isReady().then(() => {
      app.mount('#app');
    })
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`Error: ${err}`)
    throw new Error(`Error: ${err}`)
  }
})
```

I have the insert commented out so it doesn't run more than once, but when that's uncommented on the first run with a clean database those records do get into the database fine. If I query and output those to the home screen they show up.

## App.vue

My `App.vue` is right out of the [Vue SQLite App Starter Example](https://github.com/jepiqueau/vue-sqlite-app-starter):

```vue
<template>
  <ion-app>
    <suspense>
      <ion-split-pane content-id="main-content">
        <menu-component />
        <ion-router-outlet id="main-content"></ion-router-outlet>
      </ion-split-pane>
      <template #fallback>
        <div><h1>Loading ...</h1></div>
      </template>
    </suspense>
  </ion-app>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'
import {
  IonApp, 
  IonRouterOutlet, 
  IonSplitPane
} from '@ionic/vue'
import { useSQLite } from 'vue-sqlite-hook'
import MenuComponent from '@/components/MenuComponent.vue'

const app = getCurrentInstance()

if (app != null) {
  app.appContext.config.globalProperties.$sqlite = useSQLite()
}
</script>
```

The only possible wrinkle is the use of `<suspense>` but I have to use that given the async nature of getting the database connection rolling in my app components.

## App screens

1. Home screen - Does a `SELECT * FROM contacts` and outputs to screen.
2. Contact form - A form with fields for first name, last name, and email. Click event on a button runs the function that handles the insert.

`HomePage.vue`:

```vue
<template>
  <ion-page>
    <ion-header :translucent="true">
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-buttons slot="start">
          <ion-menu-button color="primary"></ion-menu-button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-title>HOME</ion-title>
        <ion-buttons slot="end">
          <ion-button @click="$router.push({ name: 'create-contact' })">ADD CONTACT</ion-button>
        </ion-buttons>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>

    <ion-content :fullscreen="true" class="ion-padding">
      <h1>HOME PAGE</h1>
      <pre>{{ JSON.stringify(contacts,null,2) }}</pre>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-page>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { getCurrentInstance, onMounted, ref } from 'vue'
import {
  IonButtons,
  IonButton,
  IonContent,
  IonHeader,
  IonMenuButton,
  IonPage,
  IonTitle,
  IonToolbar,
} from '@ionic/vue'
import { SQLiteDBConnection, SQLiteHook } from 'vue-sqlite-hook/dist'

const app = getCurrentInstance()
const sqlite: SQLiteHook = app?.appContext.config.globalProperties.$sqlite
const ret = await sqlite.checkConnectionsConsistency()
const isConn = (await sqlite.isConnection('ionic-vue-db', false)).result
let db: SQLiteDBConnection
if (ret.result && isConn) {
  db = await sqlite.retrieveConnection('ionic-vue-db', false)
} else {
  db = await sqlite.createConnection('ionic-vue-db', false, 'no-encryption', 1, false)
}

const contacts = ref()

const getContacts = async() => {
  await db.open()
  const getContactsRes = await db.query(`
    SELECT * FROM contacts;
  `)
  console.log(getContactsRes)
  return getContactsRes.values
}

onMounted(async () => {
  contacts.value = await getContacts()
})
</script>
```

`ContactForm.vue`:

```vue
<template>
  <ion-page>
    <ion-header :translucent="true">
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>CREATE CONTACT</ion-title>
        <ion-buttons slot="end">
          <ion-button @click="$router.push({ name: 'home' })">CANCEL</ion-button>
        </ion-buttons>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>

    <ion-content :fullscreen="true" class="ion-padding">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label position="fixed">First Name</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" v-model="firstName"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label position="fixed">Last Name</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" v-model="lastName"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label position="fixed">Email</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="email" v-model="email"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-button
        style="margin:12px;"
        @click="doCreateContact"
      >SAVE CONTACT</ion-button>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-page>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { getCurrentInstance, ref } from 'vue'
import {
  IonPage,
  IonHeader,
  IonToolbar,
  IonButtons,
  IonTitle,
  IonButton,
  IonContent,
  IonItem,
  IonLabel,
  IonInput,
} from '@ionic/vue'
import { SQLiteDBConnection, SQLiteHook } from 'vue-sqlite-hook/dist'
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'

const router = useRouter()

const app = getCurrentInstance()
const sqlite: SQLiteHook = app?.appContext.config.globalProperties.$sqlite
const ret = await sqlite.checkConnectionsConsistency()
const isConn = (await sqlite.isConnection('ionic-vue-db', false)).result
let db: SQLiteDBConnection
if (ret.result && isConn) {
  db = await sqlite.retrieveConnection('ionic-vue-db', false)
} else {
  db = await sqlite.createConnection('ionic-vue-db', false, 'no-encryption', 1, false)
}

const firstName = ref<string>('')
const lastName = ref<string>('')
const email = ref<string>('')

const doCreateContact = (async () => {
  await db.open()
  const res = await db.run(`
      INSERT INTO contacts (first_name, last_name, email) 
      VALUES (?, ?, ?);
    `, 
    [firstName.value, lastName.value, email.value]
  )
  console.log(res)
  firstName.value = ''
  lastName.value = ''
  email.value = ''

  const contactsRes = await db.query('SELECT * FROM contacts;')
  console.log(contactsRes)

  router.push({ name: 'home' })
})
</script>
```

## Behavior

When I fill out the form in `ContactForm.vue` and click the "Save Contact" button, the insert runs without error, and in the `console.log` of the response from `db.run` -call it shows one change and `lastId` increases.

Furthermore, the `SELECT * FROM contacts;` query that runs immediately following the insert on `ContactForm.vue` shows both the initial records inserted in `main.ts` as well as the record that was just inserted by submitting the contact form. But when the `router.push({ name: 'home' })` happens and I log the results from `SELECT * FROM contacts;` on the home screen, only the initial records inserted in `main.ts` show up.

If I then navigate from the home screen back to `ContactForm.vue` the `SELECT * from contacts;` on `ContactForm.vue` only shows the initial records inserted in `main.ts`. If however, I comment out the `router.push({ name: 'home' })` in `ContactForm.vue` so it stays on the contact form screen after a contact is added, the log of `SELECT * FROM contacts;` *does* contain the new record.

Further behavior if I stay on the contact form screen after the insert:

- If I try to insert the same email address twice it throws a unique constraint violation error.
- The console log of the insert response changes shows the `lastId` increasing as I insert multiple records.

But once I navigate back to the home screen and then go back to the contact form it's as if the inserts that I did while remaining on the contact form never happened:

- Only the three initial records insert in `main.ts` exist.
- I can insert email addresses that I previously added and not get a unique constraint violation error.
- The `lastId` starts over at `4` for the first insert.

## Questions

1. Is the initial bootstrapping in `main.ts` and `App.vue` correct?
2. Am I handling the connections in the components properly?
   I'm wondering if I have to do the `checkConnectionsConsistency()`, `isConn()`, and conditional `sqlite.retrieveConnection()` or `sqlite.createConnection()` in every component. The `vue-sqlite-hook` documentation seems to indicate you can use an `$existingConn` on the app instance, but I didn't see them doing that in their examples other than in the test of an existing connection, so it's unclear to me if you're supposed to check for that and create a connection only if needed, or if the code I have in both my components is just "how you do it.".
3. Does SQLite auto-commit or do I need to explicitly commit my inserts, or perhaps close the connection after I do an insert? (closing the connection didn't have any effect). From the behavior it seems as if I stay on the contact form screen everything works, but once you leave that screen you lose the inserts since they haven't been committed, though if that were the case I wouldn't expect them to show up in the `SELECT` query on that page.

Comment: Bit more experimentation led to the following: moving the db connection dance (check for connection, etc.) to _inside_ the doCreateContact() function, _and_ explicitly closing the connection with sqlite.closeConnection('ionic-vue-db', false) seems to make the inserts stick. Now I just need to figure out how to show the new data on the home screen without having to do a refresh even though it's reactive. I'd still love validation as to whether or not I'm doing this in even remotely the right way. :-)

Comment: onIonViewWillEnter proved to be the saving grace to get the data to load on the home screen whenever that page is it. So I feel like I'm getting close to having this all squared away, though knowing I'm handling the database connections in the best way would be great peace of mind!